# How to include multiple JS references in a single JS file, then import only that one file?

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I have the following JS files locally:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.grouping.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
```

Is there an acceptable way to import all of these into a single js file, then pull in that single file anytime I need it?

For example, placing all the above files in jqwidgets.js and adding:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets.js"></script>
```

...to the page?

Comment: Have you tried using modules?

Comment: I understand modules and I've used them. I can probably figure out how to do that, but is it the right thing to do?

Comment: There is a tutorial for this in the official documentation: [jQWidgets Integration with RequireJS](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/requirejs/requirejs_tutorial.htm)

Comment: That's cool. I'm new to jQWidgets... I think I can apply that. This question is more for any project where I have to bring in a lot of JS files and I want to bring them into a single file and deliver them to my page with just one file. Thoughts on that?